# Why did Ben get trapped in the parallel paradox/mirrors?

Tags: analysis, mirrors

In the end of the movie [*Mirrors*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0790686/), Ben got trapped in the parallel paradox/mirror. The majority of us would have thought that this aspect has to play a crucial role in its sequel *Mirrors 2*, but none of the things relating to this incident are shown in Mirrors.

Any ideas why Ben got trapped in the end?

Answer (score 3):

My interpretation of the film is that, when somebody dies they enters in the mirror world. So the last scene for me is not an open end for the sequels but to show that Ben has been died. The last fight was too dangerous for Ben to survive, so he died when the building collapsed.